# Display, scale and zoom huge custom painting

Tags: java, swing, zooming, jscrollpane, affinetransform

I have to draw some points and a polygon to link them together. 
The custom painting will be done on a JPanel with a JScrollPane and supports some scaling/zooming via AffineTransformation. After setting the JPanels preferred size to the required dimension defined by the points coordinates and doing a revalidate, the drawing is properly displayed and could be scrolled. 
Everything is fine as long as the points coordinates dont't exceed some limits set by the limits of datatype integer, zooming and the Dimension class.

Example: 
Imagine four points at coordinates

```
(10000,10000), (10000,-10000), (-10000,10000), (-10000,-10000).
```

They define the cornes of a square with the point of origin at its center. The short form of my paintComponent method:

```java
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    // Backup original transform
    AffineTransform originalTransform = g2d.getTransform();

    // Set virtual drawing area to scroll through, scaled by zoomfactor
    double viewZoomFactor = 1.0; // Will be set to other values != 1.0 later
    // Because of the points coordinates a rectangle of size 20000 by 20000 is required
    this.setPreferedSize(new Dimension(20000 * viewZoomFactor,20000 * viewZoomFactor));
    this.revalidate();

    // Move point of origin to the center 
    Point pointOfOrigin = new Point(10000, 10000);
    // Translate all points and revert y-direction
    AffineTransform t = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
                pointOfOrigin.x, this.getHeight() - pointOfOrigin.y)
    t.scale(viewZoomFactor, -viewZoomFactor);
    g2d.transform(t);

    this.drawPointsAndPolygonOnPanel();

    // Restore original transform
    g2d.setTransform(originalTransform);
}
```

While zoomFactor == 1.0 one pixel equaltes to exactly one coordinate value.

Because of their constructor `Point(int, int)` the points could be placed inside a plane of [Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE] by [Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE]. The JPanels preferred size is of type `Dimension(int,int)`. Normally the values of width and height are non-negative integers.

Now the problem comes with huge coordinates values: Imagine a set of points like these:

```java
(Integer.MAX_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE), 
(Integer.MAX_VALUE,Integer.MIN_VALUE), 
(Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE), 
(Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MIN_VALUE)
```

My first thought was to introduce another scale factor to scale all coordinate values down:

```java
t.scale(viewZoomFactor * dataZoomFactor, -viewZoomFactor * dataZoomFactor);
```

This will cause the pixel to coordinate value ratio to decrease: 1 pixel = 1/dataZoomFactor coordinate values at viewZoomFactor = 1.0.

How can I achieve a 1:1 scaled, scrollable visible section of the whole drawing when the points to draw are placed at the above mentioned extreme positions? 
What if viewZoomFactor > 1.0 (magnifier)?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: My first thought is to transform the viewport to "world space", f.e. "viewport is at (150, 20) in the space of these points, with dimensions (20, 20)"; I suppose transform the raw viewport (0, 0, 400, 300) using the inverse transform you're using above. Then you can clip the polygon(s) to the viewport without transforming the points, and finally transform the clipped polygons to viewport space and render.